# Detect SpriteKit button press overlay from SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I have a simple HUD that I built using sprite kit that is an overlay on my 3d scene kit game. I have a visible "Main Menu" button that displays but for the life of me I can not detect that it's being pressed.

Here is how the overlay is being setup.

```
    sceneView = self.view as! GameSCNView
    scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/MainScene.scn")
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.overlaySKScene = OverlayScene(size: sceneView.bounds.size)
    overlayScene = sceneView.overlaySKScene as! OverlayScene
    overlayScene.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Now here is the overlay scene that is being created.

```
class OverlayScene : SKScene {

var timeLabel:SKLabelNode!
var mainMenu:SKSpriteNode!

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)

    //setup the overlay scene
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

    //automatically resize to fill the viewport

    let widthScale = size.width / 1024
    let heightScale = size.height / 768

    self.scaleMode = .resizeFill

    // Initialize the Score
    timeLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Time: 0")
    timeLabel.position = CGPoint(x: -size.width * 0.35, y: size.height*0.45)
    timeLabel.fontName = "AmericanTypewriter-Bold"
    timeLabel.fontSize = 36 * widthScale
    timeLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    addChild(timeLabel)

    mainMenu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MainMenu_ButtonHighlighted-IpadMini.png")
    mainMenu.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    mainMenu.xScale = widthScale
    mainMenu.yScale = heightScale
    mainMenu.position = CGPoint(x: -size.width * 0.35, y: size.height*0.45)
    mainMenu.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    mainMenu.zPosition = 0
    addChild(mainMenu)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if mainMenu.contains(location) {
            print("Main Menu Touch Began")
        }
    }
}


override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if mainMenu.contains(location) {
            print("Main Menu Touch Ended")
        }
    }
}
}
```

My expected output would be to see "Main Menu Touch Began" and "Main Menu Touch Ended" but I am not getting anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you change `isUserInteractionEnabled` to be `true` for both your `mainMenu` and your `OverlayScene`?

Comment: Nothing, and I have also found that making it false makes the button fire whereas true does not. A bit counter-intuitive in my opinion. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Yeah that's what this guy seems to have figured out too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850541/skspritenode-userinteractionenabled-not-working

Comment: Can you see whether touchesBegan and touchedEnded is called at all and just does not make it into the if statement?

Comment: By putting the print outside of the for statements and outside of the if statements I am getting no output. So they are not being called when pressing the button or any other part of the SKScene

Comment: What happens if you move your "touches code" to the outer class? I mean, not the `OverlayScene` but the class where you add that node?

Comment: You do not need to manually scale, let the system work for you, and you won't see these problems

Comment: `isUserInteractionEnabled` means the object captures the touch events, it is not counter-intuitive.  You do not want your button to handle the code, you want your scene to handle the code, thus you want it to be false.  Your overlay scene is set to false, which means  it is never going to get touch events

Comment: @pbodsk I have tried adding it to the GameViewController where the overlaySKScene is applied but it also did respond to any touches began or ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) By having isUserInteractionEnabled set to false on your overlay, your overlay is never going to receive touch events.

2) With you manually scaling, you open yourself up to screwing around with your math.  SpriteKit is designed to handle scaling for you, that is why scaleMode exists.  It makes a lot more sense to scale once at the very end up process, then to constantly scale every little thing.

Do the following changes, and it should work for you.

Set

`overlayScene.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

To allow your scene to receive touches,

then clean up your code:

```
class OverlayScene : SKScene {

    var timeLabel:SKLabelNode!
    var mainMenu:SKSpriteNode!
    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size:size)
    }
    convenience override init() {

        self.init(size: CGSize(width:1024,height:768))

            //setup the overlay scene
            self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

            //automatically resize to fill the viewport



            self.scaleMode = .fill

            // Initialize the Score
            timeLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Time: 0")
            timeLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.35, y: size.height*0.45)
            timeLabel.fontName = "AmericanTypewriter-Bold"
            timeLabel.fontSize = 36
            timeLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
            addChild(timeLabel)

            mainMenu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MainMenu_ButtonHighlighted-IpadMini.png")
            mainMenu.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

            mainMenu.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.35, y: size.height*0.45)
            mainMenu.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            mainMenu.zPosition = 0
            addChild(mainMenu)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            if mainMenu == self.atPoint(location) {
                print("Main Menu Touch Began")
            }
        }
    }


    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            if mainMenu == self.atPoint(location) {
                print("Main Menu Touch Ended")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use:

```
sceneView.overlaySKScene = OverlayScene()
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a much more controlled way of scaling the HUD but these changes did not resolve the problem. I copied your code verbatim and received an error on `self(size: CGSize(width:1024,height:768)` I replaced it with `super.init(size: CGSize(width:1024,height:768))` this changed the scaling to a simplified form but the `sceneView.overlaySKScene = OverlayScene()` and `overlayScene.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` had no effect on the touches began function. Thank you for your attempt though.

Comment: Why did you change it?  That is a convenience init, it needs self not super

Comment: I changed it because your code throws an error: `Cannot call value of non-function type 'OverlayScene'`

Comment: I fixed it for you

Comment: I was wondering why you were using a negative width size lol.  You want time on the left of the screen You can just used a specific number to place it wherever you want.  I tested my code and it works, so if you are not getting in the touchesBegan function, then you have something else going on.

Comment: The way the anchor point is set it places the root in the center of the screen. This is just my personal preference on how to place the nodes to account for varying screen sizes. Also are you placing the overlay scene over a SceneKit scene? I also have a SCNSceneRenderer function that handles an accelerometer I wonder if that is overriding the touches began and ended. @knightofdragon

Comment: Yes, i am actually placing it over an ar scenekit scene to cover that base as well.  I do not know where your problem lies,  create a brand new project and copy my code into it to see that it works, then compare to your code to see where you are going wrong.